# How can I use AlphaAnimation on a bitmap pre API 11

Tags: android, animation, alpha

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9087786/2359488) link shows how to use AlphaAnimation on a View pre API 11.

What I have to animate now works with API 11 and above.

```
    ObjectAnimator fader = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(paint1,"alpha", 250, 00);
        fader.setDuration(1000);
        fader.setRepeatCount(0);
        fader.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.RESTART);
        fader.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                invalidate();
            }
        });
```

and then in onDraw() method, I animate my bitmap as

```
    @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.save();
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap1, x, y  , paint1);         
    canvas.restore();
}
```

What API can I use to make it work with API 8 ?

Comment: Why not use AlphaAnimation, not ObjectAnimator?

Comment: AlphaAnimation works only on Views, whereas I want to animate the bitmap OBJECTS within my view. Those bitmaps I draw within my canvas with specified alpha valued paint.

ObjectAnimator has been introduced in API11. I want to support API8 as well.